# How to handle Runtime Error after autofiltering returns no data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of sheets with VBA macros which transfer data after autofiltering.

When a sheet has no data after autofiltering, the macro brings up runtime error 1004 on the line

```
Workbooks("Predictology-Reports.xlsx").Sheets("FAL") _
          .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Here is the full macro of one of them

```vb
Sub FALAYS()
    Dim arr, ws As Worksheet, lc As Long, lr As Long

    arr = Array("L.FAL_19_New_Summer2", "L.FA_FAL_3", "L.FAL_19_New_Summer")

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'range from A1 to last column header and last row
    lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lr = ws.Cells.Find("*", after:=ws.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   
    With ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(lr, lc))
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        If .Rows.Count - 1 > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
      
    Workbooks("Predictology-Reports.xlsx").Sheets("FAL") _
          .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a range variable to the visible rows, then check to see if that got set before you copy/paste.

```vb
Sub FALAYS()
    Dim arr, ws As Worksheet, lc As Long, lr As Long, rngCopy As Range

    arr = Array("L.FAL_19_New_Summer2", "L.FA_FAL_3", "L.FAL_19_New_Summer")

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    'range from A1 to last column header and last row
    lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lr = ws.Cells.Find("*", after:=ws.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   
    With ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(lr, lc))
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        If .Rows.Count  > 1 Then
        
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngCopy = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                rngCopy.Copy
                Workbooks("Predictology-Reports.xlsx").Sheets("FAL") _
                    .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If   'have anything to copy
        
        End If
    End With
      
End Sub
```

If this is a common task then pull it out into its own Sub:

```vb
'given a [filtered] table rngTable, copy visible data rows as values to rngDestination
Sub CopyVisibleRows(rngTable As Range, rngDestination As Range)
    Dim rngVis As Range
    If rngTable.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngVis = rngTable.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngTable.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then
            rngVis.Copy
            rngDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    End If 'any source rows
End Sub
```

which reduces your original code to something like:

```vb
Sub FALAYS()
    Dim arr, ws As Worksheet, lc As Long, lr As Long, tbl As Range

    arr = Array("L.FAL_19_New_Summer2", "L.FA_FAL_3", "L.FAL_19_New_Summer")

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    'range from A1 to last column header and last row
    lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lr = ws.Cells.Find("*", after:=ws.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set tbl = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(lr, lc))
    With tbl
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        If .Rows.Count  > 1 Then
        
            CopyVisibleRows  tbl, Workbooks("Predictology-Reports.xlsx").Sheets("FAL") _
                                    .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)          
        
        End If
    End With
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers Tim
That brings up the same RTE, but on the following line
```Set sourceRange = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)```

Comment: I don't have that line?

Comment: Your code has that line directly after this line Tim
```' Set the cells to the source range``` It is the 24th line of code

Comment: Are you talking about the other answer from Ricardo ?

Comment: Sincere apologies Tim. You're spot on. I had scrolled too far and thought it was still part of your response. Now that I have replaced the code with yours, it seems to behave perfectly, with no halt when there is no data to copy. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of improvements you could make to this code, but it should give you a starting point.

I'm assigning the filtered cells to a range, if there are cells, the range is "something".

Then copying the range to the sheet directly (you could skip the copy, paste method by transferring the values to the cells).

Tip: Try to avoid `On Error Resume Next` unless you know what you're doing and it is strictly necessary.

Read the comments and adjust the code to your needs.

EDIT: Added OERN as per Tim's suggestion

**Code**

```
Public Sub FALAYS()
    
    Dim arrValues As Variant
    arrValues = Array("L.FAL_19_New_Summer2", "L.FA_FAL_3", "L.FAL_19_New_Summer")
    
    ' Set the target workbook and sheet
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks("Predictology-Reports.xlsx")
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("FAL")
    
    ' Set the source sheet and range
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim sourceColumn As Long
    Dim sourceRow As Long
    Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    'range from A1 to last column header and last row
    sourceColumn = sourceSheet.Cells(1, sourceSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    sourceRow = sourceSheet.Cells.Find("*", after:=sourceSheet.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    
    With sourceSheet.Range("A1", sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRow, sourceColumn))
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arrValues, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        If .Rows.Count - 1 > 0 Then
            
            ' Set the cells to the source range
            On Error Resume Next
            Set sourceRange = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error Goto 0
            
            ' Validate if the source range has cells
            If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then
                sourceRange.Copy targetSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works.